# How come I can edit a post anywhere, but my approval alone on someone else's edit is not enough?

Tags: support, edits, review, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I found out that:

- I have enough reputation to edit anything without needing my edit to be peer-reviewed.
- If I come to a question for which an edit was proposed and approve it, it doesn't apply immediately because "it needs one more approval".

This behavior seems a bit inconsistent to me. Is it a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as Jonsca, JonW and I all found things in your post to be edited, so it is that sometimes you may miss a thing or two as well to make sure the post is most-correct.

Had you "improved" the edit instead of "approving" it, you would have bypassed that mechanism.

---

Also, there are a few bad-apples that spoil it for everyone. They just blindly approve stuff without reading it, so this is a technology-solution to a people-problem.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm glad you noticed that I did a substandard edit intentionally. That was to prove your point. Yes. ;) * cough*

Answer (score 0):

You now have the privilege to edit posts without having your edit reviewed.

The privilege give you access to the review queue not the power to accept or deny edit on your own. As stated here in the privilege section :

> **Reviewing suggested edits**
>
> In addition, users with this privilege level also get access to the suggested edits queue. The queue has a list of posts which have been edited upon by users who don't have edit privileges. This queue can be accessed over at the suggested edits tab in the review section.
> Users with this privilege level get access to the Low Quality Posts list where they can improved the low quality posts, or suggest they are deleted.